# Create new org-roam node ignoring pre selected existing nodes

Tags: org-roam

`C-c n f` is bound to `org-roam-node-find` in my setup.

I can search existing nodes or create a new one if it does not exist yet. Assume that there still is a node with the title `Foobar in summer` and I want to create a new node with title `summer`.

This is not possible because when I type `summer` (after `C-c n f`) the existing node `Foobar in summer` is pre selected. When I hit `ENTER` the existing node opens in a new buffer instead of a new created node (capture buffer?) with title `summer`.

How can I create a new node preventing preselection of existing nodes?

Here is a minimal `init.el` and a screen recording:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; === Package setup ===
(require 'package)

(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
             ("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")
             ("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
;; Initializes the package infrastructure
(package-initialize)

;; === use-package ==
;; use-package to simplify the config file
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(require 'use-package)
(setq use-package-always-ensure 't)

;; === Improved search field
; M-o opens "context menu" of a search item
(use-package ivy
  :diminish
  :bind (("C-s" . swiper))
  :config
  (ivy-mode 1))

;; === Add docstring column to function search results
(use-package ivy-rich
    :init
    (ivy-rich-mode 1))

(use-package org-roam
  :init  ; is called before the package is loaded
  (setq org-roam-v2-ack t)  ; do not show migration warning after startup
  :custom
  (org-roam-directory "~/tab-cloud/my.org-roam")
  :bind (("C-c n l" . org-roam-buffer-toggle)
     ("C-c n f" . org-roam-node-find)
     ("C-c n i" . org-roam-node-insert)
     )
  :config
  (org-roam-db-autosync-mode)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce that: I can enter `summer` even if it shows `Foobar in summer` in the completions list. OTOH, I cannot enter a space in the title (although I can modify it after the fact).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For common completion frameworks (e.g. ivy, vertico), `<enter>` is used to select candidates.

For `vertico`, your case requires `M-<return>` (`vertico-exit-input`).

For `ivy`, it is `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`).

The corresponding function of other completion frameworks can be found in the keymap or README.

Comment: For vertico, it seems that vertico-exit-input changed to M-return.

Comment: Thank @ElDiegoEfe for pointing this out, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the prompt line can be made selectable with `(setq ivy-use-selectable-prompt t)`.

Solution based on: https://org-roam.discourse.group/t/create-new-org-roam-node-ignoring-pre-selected-existing-nodes/2448?u=2meufy0iakxhveq31